# Eclipse show erro in HQL NamedQueries but Application Works

Tags: java, eclipse, hibernate, jpa

I have a NamedQuery like bellow:

```
@Entity
@DiscriminatorValue(value = "20")
@NamedQueries(value = { @NamedQuery(name = "SituacaoFluxo.findAll", query = "SELECT c FROM SituacaoFluxo c ORDER BY c.descricao") })
public class SituacaoFluxo extends BaseSituacao {

 public static final String FIND_ALL = "SituacaoFluxo.findAll";
}
```

The field `descricao` exists in class `BaseSituacao`. But Eclipse show the following error:

```
The state field path 'c.descricao' cannot be resolved to a valid
```

See my BaseSituacao class

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "base_situacao")
@Inheritance(strategy = javax.persistence.InheritanceType.SINGLE_TABLE)
@DiscriminatorColumn(name = "tipo", discriminatorType = javax.persistence.DiscriminatorType.INTEGER)
public class BaseSituacao extends AbstractBean {
```

Comment: Try to clean and rebuild your project.

Comment: I already tried it one million times :D, even restart all computer.

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar query with a hibernate entity subclass in my project.

I tried to replicate your problem but was unsuccessful.

I do use the following annotation:

```
@PrimaryKeyJoinColumn(name="primary_key_id_field")
```

where primary_key_id_field is the unique key of the base class.

Add this just above the class declaration.

You could try that and see if it helps.

Comment: Because of my relationship of SituacaoFluxo with BaseSituacao i think that i can't use @PrimaryKeyJoinColumn. I edited my post with my "BaseSituacao.java" and you can see what i'm talking about